# Subscribing to custom events of my deployed program?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, subscription

This is my program which emits TokensPaid event on-chain. How can I subscribe to TokensPaid event in NodeJS so that whenever a user does a transaction on-chain, it is stored in the db on backend.

```
pub struct TokensPaid {
    #[index]
    pub user: Pubkey,
    pub currency: String,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub decimal: u8
}

**inside the function**
emit!(TokensPaid {
      user: *ctx.accounts.signer.key,
      currency: currency,
      amount: amount,
      decimal: mint.decimals
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `logsSubscribe` websocket endpoint for the name of the event that you're looking to track, ie:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "logsSubscribe",
  "params": [
    {
      "mentions": [ "<YOUR_PROGRAM_ID_AS_BASE_58>" ]
    },
    {
      "commitment": "finalized"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then any time you see the `TokensPaid` log, you can store the info in the database.

More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe

Otherwise, it appears that Anchor TS provides some easy helpers for subscribing to the logs: https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/events.html#subscribing-to-events